# DNS URLs in Azure AD B2C don't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

The app only accepts localhost URLs, and anything else will give an error and refuses to save the  app.

This issue makes the app only works when trying it on the hosting machine, but not on any other  device.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enter a HTTPS url, otherwise you will see this error: "Please enter a valid Url string"

You are allowed to use 1 domain name and localhost.

This will work:

```
https://my.dummy.site
https://localhost
```

This will not work:

```
https://my.dummy.site
https://my.other.domain
https://localhost
```

In this last example the error being displayed is: "You may not use more than 1 external domain(s)"

Comment: did that and it worked, the letter 's' saved the day, thanks

Comment: also, I don't need to add localhost anymore, I just added the line "127.0.0.1 madpotato.ddns.net" it in the hosts file in system32/drivers/etc/