# ReturnUri to Localhost

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

During development the team prefer to develop against a local database and local IIS Express web server.

We tried to configure an address of http://localhost:<port>/ in the Azure AD B2C application configuration as a return URI, but this isn't permitted (technically it should work, although I can see why it isn't permitted).  So at the moment, when anyone signs in, it returns them to the test server URL.

We'd like to be returned to our local development server instance.  Is there any way that people know of to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use localhost, but make sure to use https:

```
https://localhost:<port>
```

See also this answer: [DNS URLs in Azure AD B2C don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408950/dns-urls-in-azure-ad-b2c-dont-work/36424368#36424368)

Just a self signed certificate is enough to make this work. We use this a lot (together with B2C) for our development machines.